# using subsonic with mysql

Tags: c#, mysql, subsonic

I was wondering if anyone knows a reference on how to configure subsonic 3.0 to use mySQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.subsonicproject.com/docs/Using_ActiveRecord

All in the Docs, run through that.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a post on my experience doing this

You can find it here:

[Setting up SubSonic and MySQL](http://jeffgos.tumblr.com/post/1594498383/subsonic-and-mysql)